# Decode JSON one time and shows data

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

Well, from the beginning. I have a link to the API from which I download data to the website:

```
<?php
$api = file_get_contents('LINK DO API');
$decoded_json = json_decode($api, true);
$data = $decoded_json['data'];
$dane = $data['temp_and_humidity_ch3']['temperature'];
  
{
  echo $dane['value'].$dane['unit'];
}
?>
```

it works and everything shows up. The problem is that I have 19 such data to download and display. When I insert the same code 19 times, changing only the displayed parameter, the page instead of loading less than a second takes almost 8 seconds... I have no idea how to do it in such a way that the whole thing is downloaded only once and then only displayed, without re-decoding the JSON.

Comment: It's not the decoding and displaying that takes a long time, it's the fetching of the data from the the external URL. Since we have no idea what API you're using we cannot know if your 19 calls can be done in 1.

Comment: @KIKO Software: it's about the Ecowitt API. If the above code is used once, the whole thing works fast, if 19 - slow.
Link to DOCS API: https://doc.ecowitt.net/web/#/apiv3en?page_id=17

Comment: OK, it's an API for a weatherstation. You have 19 of those? Just asking. It seems the api/v3/device/real_time endpoint returns all real time information for a single device. If you have 1 device, 1 call should suffice.

Comment: There is only one station, there are 19 weather parameters that I want to display, e.g. temperature, wind, pressure. As a result, I have to use the above-mentioned code as many as 19 times, and I want to limit it to decoding the whole thing once and only displaying a given parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, a single API call returns all the values you need. Of course I cannot test this, but try this code:

```php
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('LINK DO API');
$data = json_decode($json)->data;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';

foreach (range(1, 8) as $channelNo) {
  $temperature = $data->{'temp_and_humidity_ch' . $channelNo}->temperature;
  echo "ChannelchannelNo {$temperature->value}{$temperature->unit}<br>";
}
```

This code should first show you all the data that the API returns and then give you the temperature readings of all 8 channels with one API call.

Comment: yes, it shows all the parameters I want, but there is still a problem.  I will describe it again.  I want to download everything from the API once and then with code (I don't know which) to display it individually in divs that I have on the website template.

Comment: @Yulia94: I understand. We have established that you only need one API call, and that this returns all the data you need. The problem remaining is how to render this data into individual HTML tags. I think you should ask a new question with this problem. Present the data structure you have, and your website template, and ask how to put the data in the template. Your original question was about having to call an API 19 times, and it taking 8 seconds. That problem has been solved.